# Sitecore Web Forms for Marketers Installation Issue

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

Good Afternoon All,

We are running Sitecore 8.1. When installing WFFM using the package *Web Forms for Marketers 8.1 rev. 151217.zip*, both my colleague and I get the error "Background process failed: Failed to delete the file sitecore\website\NOT_A_VALID_FILESYSTEM_PATH".

If we delete the folder then retry the installation, the package appears to install correctly, but when we try to view any page on the site the error "The view xyz must derive from ViewPage, ViewPage..."

Also, there is no issue when installing WFFM on any of our QA servers, only on our develop workstations.

Has anyone ever had a similar issue when installing WFFM?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with permissions - as this is a dev environment have you tried configuring full control NETWORKSERVICE on you data and webroot folders?

Comment: @richieb which revision of 8.1? Going to see if I can replicate it on a sandbox?

Comment: Latest rev of 8.1 and the WFFM you mention above which is latest works fine for me. @IanGraham Is correct. Check the app pool identity and ensure this has permissions over the website root and all child locations.

Comment: You can use process monitor, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645, and filter on status of access denied to identify what and who is blocking the install. But like Ian said, setting you app pool to network service and giving network service full control of your web folder should do it.